# Recycle a data flow task for multiple tables with different DDL using concatenated output

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have 40 extracts with all different metadata and columns; so instead of writing 40 dataflow tasks for each extract, I want to use one tasks with expressions/variables to set up the output file connection. The problem is of course data flow tasks require metadata ahead of time. I have a potential solution in that I can `CONCAT` the output of the extracts with the delimiter so it returns one long string for every extract, so now the metadata is always the same. The problem is they want the data sorted. I've tried the following logic in SQL but it won't preserve ordering.

```
SELECT
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3
INTO
    #temp
FROM
    table;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cx_Table ON #temp (Column2);

SELECT
    'Column1|Column2|Column3'

UNION ALL

SELECT
    CONCAT(Column1 + '|' + Column2 + '|' + Column3)
FROM
    #temp;
```

The problem is I can't use an `ORDER BY` in the the concatenated `SELECT` because `Column2` doesn't exist as an output column. I tried imposing an order on the temp table by using a clustered index, but the `UNION` ruins order. I could output the data unordered to the file then sort it using a C# or .NET script but this feels horribly inefficient. Also some extracts have multiple columns listed in the `ORDER BY`.

Is there a way to deal with heterogeneous data like this? Currently, I have a C# script task that basically does row by row inserts into the file and is horribly slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is I can't use an ORDER BY in the the concatenated SELECT
>   because Column2 doesn't exist as an output column.

I don't know if `CONCAT()` introduces some specific limitation, but you can absolutely do this (I just tested it):

```
SELECT
    Column1 + '|' + Column2 + '|' + Column3 AS ConcatCol
FROM
    #temp
ORDER BY Column2;
```

EDIT based on comment:

Well, I believe you CAN do `ORDER BY` in CTE or Subquery if you use the `TOP` clause, but to include it in your union AND get the overall ORDER you want, you will need to do the UNION before you do the CONCAT:

```
SELECT Col1+'|'+Col2+'|'+Col3 AS ConcatCol
FROM  (
SELECT
    'Column1' AS Col1 , 'Column2' AS Col2, 'Column3' AS Col3
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM
    #temp;
ORDER BY {whatever you need to do here}
) u
```

If it complains about an ORDER BY in the derived table, you can try either using the TOP clause, or use an intermediary #temp table.

Comment: So that works, yeah. I was using CONCAT to deal with NULLs. But I can't union it with the header row since Column2 doesn't exist there. I can't do an ORDER BY  in a CTE or subquery either.

Comment: I ended up using the ROW_NUMBER() function and applying the order by there. The header row is of course row 0, so I can sort the unioned output